# How to send FCM notification to rarely used app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have a Cordova app that receives secure messages from a service provider, through our servers, to an app installed on a phone by the user. However, the app may be rarely used (in the order of 12 months or so). In the event that the provider needs to contact the user we currently send an FCM notification. The problem is that because we don't want to place any drain on the user's battery for a service that they rarely use (although is extremely valuable) then we don't try and run anything in the background - which means that according to the firebase document [Lifetime of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) the message will be discarded if the user doesn't open the app for one month.
The referenced doc states:

> If the device has not connected to FCM for more than one month, FCM still accepts the message but immediately discards it. If the device connects within four weeks of the last data message you sent to it, your client receives the onDeletedMessages() callback. The app can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync from the app server.

How are we supposed to inform the user that there is a message for them?

I understand why such a precaution *can* make sense, but what options exist to allow us to receive the notification causing minimal impact on the users' device?

Comment: Are you running into an actual, observed problem where messages are not received in the case you're describing?  Or are you just concerned that the message might not make it?

Comment: We appear to experience this. However, upon re-reading the document it doesn't explicitly state that the app must be launched and may, therefore, be inferring that the device itself is disabled (eg powered off) for one month

Comment: The app must be launched at least once, so that it can collect a device token that uniquely identifies that device.  If the device token ever changes, and your app is not launched again after that, then you are out of luck.  The app needs to be launched again to collect that new token.  You could perhaps arrange to have your app launch periodically for a short period of time in order to check if the token changed. Definitely possible on Android.  Don't know about iOS.